# Is it impossible to mix fileupload and raw json in asp core web api?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, postman

I've been trying for weeks to get my API to accept file uploads, as well as other raw data in json. The API is quite large, and is built for users to being able to create a claim/request. One aspect of it is that they should be able to upload files, if needed. I use postman to test the API. However, as I've discovered it is not possible to mix methods where you send both a raw json request and a form-data to upload files. I've tried modelbinding etcetera to try and solve this problem but I haven't had any success. The only success I have is when i create a seperate method for file uploading in the controller. But  it's not optimal as a user is supposed to upload files in the same request as they are uploading other information/data.

If anyone has any good idea on how to solve this I would be grateful.

My controller looks like following:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task < IActionResult > AddRequest(Request model) {

   if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
     return BadRequest(ModelState);
   }

   try {
     await _request.AddRequest(model);
   } catch (Exception ex) {

     return BadRequest(ex.Message);
   }

   return Ok();
 }
```

The controller is only handeling the HttpPost and the request. The actual methods etcetera is in a viewmodel class as following:

```
     public async Task < bool > AddRequest(Request model) {
    
         bool CreateRequest = true;
         int requestID = 0;
         int claimID = 0;
    
         //First Create the Request
         foreach(Service item in model.Service) {
             //First Create the Request
             if (CreateRequest) {
    
               var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
    
               parameters.Add("WorkshopEmail", model.WorkshopEmail);
               parameters.Add("WorkshopContactperson", model.WorkshopContactperson);
               parameters.Add("WorkshopCellphone", model.WorkshopCellphone);
               parameters.Add("IncVat", model.IncVat); /
               parameters.Add("ExlVat", model.ExlVat);
    
               try {
                           var requestIDenum = await _sqlconnection.QueryAsync<int> 
                           ($ @ "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Request]

                           ([WorkshopEmail], [WorkshopContactperson], [WorkshopCellphone], [IncVat],
                           [ExlVat]) VALUES(@WorkshopEmail, @WorkshopContactperson, @WorkshopCellphone, 
                           @IncVat, @ExlVat); SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
                           ",parameters);
                           requestID = requestIDenum.First(); CreateRequest = false;
    
                 }
                 catch (Exception ex) {
    
                   int hej = 0;
                 }
               }
```

The AddRequest method goes on for quite a while, with different options. The idea is that a fileupload could be something similar to:

```
  if (item.fileuploadresults != null)
  {
  // add files to database here
  }
```

When sending a request in postman the json looks something like:

```
{
   "workshopEmail":"workshopemail",
   "workshopContactperson":"workshopcontactperson",
   "workshopCellphone":"workshopcellphone",
   "incVat":"7",
   "exlVat":"3",
   "Service":[
      // add service data
   ]
```

This is part of the api, as the whole would be a lot of code. But for example in "Service" there is further information that can be added.

Now, is it impossible to add a file-upload to the api and test it in postman to store files in the database? Or is there a way that makes it possible to keep bilding the request api without creating a seperate method in the controller?

Comment: You _can_ files & json in a single request. Look up multipart requests.

Comment: Hi @ajdi871, any updates about thise case? if the answer can help resolve the issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @FeiHan i have not been able to work out a solution yet unfortunately. I wanted to be able to send files and json data in the same request, but it does not work without splitting them in some way, ex: different controller methods or someting similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone is still wondering about this question, I followed the suggestion i got from @IhorKostrov and created a multipart/form-data request. The solution can be found: [using jsonData as a key value to send mixed data in asp: Does not update the database with the values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68498411/using-jsondata-as-a-key-value-to-send-mixed-data-in-asp-does-not-update-the-dat).

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar problem and I did some hacks, I don't know if it is ok for you but here what you can do.

Your controller method needs to handle multipart/form-data requests, then in this form-data request you need to specify a `data` field, that will contain your raw JSON. After that put to your form-data request some file with a unique key, and put this key to your JSON for the image field. In the end, you will get the request like this

[image]

Then you can create some middleware where you need to modify your request data, put file data into the JSON and map it to some request class

Comment: did you set the content-type to multipart/form-data? I keep getting a 400 bad request when trying this

Comment: @ajdi871, yeah, but the postman does it for you. Maybe you need to modify your controller or model in which you try to map your request

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to post file(s) with other additional data in one request, you can try:

**Approach 1:** define a string-type property in your `Request` model class, then include and pass base64-encoded file in your json data while you make http request.

**Approach 2:** define an `IFormFile` type property in model class, then pass data through `FormData` instead of passing it in json data.

```
public class Request
{
    public string workshopEmail { get; set; }
    public string workshopContactperson { get; set; }

    //...
    //other properties
    //...

    public IFormFile fileupload { get; set; }
}
```

*apply `[FromForm]` attribute to action parameter*

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddRequest([FromForm]Request model)
{
    //...
```

For uploading files in ASP.NET Core, please check this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-5.0