# Combine Json and file upload in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm trying to send a form with Angular to a controller that contains json and a file.

```
[HttpPost("Save", Name = "SaveReportRequest")]
public ActionResult<ReportRequestBean> Save([Bind("deviceType,buildType,version,qGateDate,notes")]
            ReportRequestModel reportRequest, IFormFile file)
{
    // Validate reportRequest
    if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid ModelState");
    }

    if (ValidateQGateDate(reportRequest.QGateDate) == false)
    {
        return BadRequest("QGateDate is outside of min or max.");
    }
}
```

But all I get is

[07:22:31 INF] Request finished HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:5001/api/ReportRequest/Save application/json 130 - 415 175 application/problem+json;+charset=utf-8 20.0784ms

How can I set the right `Content-Type` or how do I build it to make it work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41367602/upload-files-and-json-in-asp-net-core-web-api

Comment: Maybe you can try define an IFormFile type property in model class, then pass data through `FormData` instead of passing it in json data.You can  read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68222731/is-it-impossible-to-mix-fileupload-and-raw-json-in-asp-core-web-api) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest solution was to upload the file one by one and save them in a temp file.
Then when I save the Form, I load the temp file and save it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is, send file inside your model

```
public class RequestModel
{
 ... (other properties)
 public IFormFile file { get; set; }
}
```

[image]